# Disable android firebase messaging programmatically

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android firebase, i'am building my first app, when the user launches the app he will be asked to authenticate over my own authentification web service, there is tow types of accounts the one will have the firebase-messaging and the other is just a normal user so he won't need firebase.

I followed firebase doc and was able to send messages but i can't disable or prevent firebase from lunching before the user is connected as only one type of user will use it and want to create the user's token when the user authenticates successfully so i can send it to my back-end server when **onTokenRefresh** is fired.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can prevent him from getting firebase message.

Comment: @jagapathi I know that but in that case the service will be runnig for nothing

Comment: you mean firebase service? @souhail-ben-slimene

Comment: yes,the user won't need the service so it will be running for no reason

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it.
In onTokenRefresh just check if user is loged in and only then upload new token.